# Laravel show latest post on homepage

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display the latest post, posted on my website.
I have a vague idea of how it needs to be done but I'm not 100% sure.
I think I need to do something like this in my PostController.php

```
public function index()
 {
    $laatstepost = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1)->get();

    return View('showposts')->with('laatsteposts', $laatstepost);
 }
```

And then something like this in my view.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <h3>{{ $laatsteposts->title }}</h3>
       <p>{{ $laatsteposts->text}}</p>
       <a href="{{ Link to latest post}}" class="post-read-more">Lees meer...</a>
 </div>
```

I don't know if I'm heading the right way or that I'm completely off track. If u guys can help me out that would be great! Thanks

Here is a screenshot of where it needs to be displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vWz9.jpg

If I miss code that is needed for this, Tell me

Answer (score 1):

Use the `first()` method to get an object instead of collection:

```
public function index()
{
   $laatstepost = Post::latest()->first();

   return view('showposts')->with('laatsteposts', $laatstepost);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3>{{ $laatsteposts->title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $laatsteposts->text }}</p>
    <a href="{{ Link to latest post}}" class="post-read-more">Lees meer...</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use your code to get a collection with just one element and display data in the view using `first()` collection method:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3>{{ $laatsteposts->first()->title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $laatsteposts->first()->text }}</p>
    <a href="{{ Link to latest post}}" class="post-read-more">Lees meer...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it, unfortunately, does not work. I get the following error `Undefined variable: laatstepost` If i type in the view `{{ $laatsteposts->title}}`.

Comment: @feudelcosine148 the error says about `laatstepost`. This means you're using `$laatstepost` instead of `$laatsteposts` somewhere in the view.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. I just display the same error but with an s attached to `$laatstepost`

Comment: @feudelcosine148 you do not pass this variable to the view, why do you expect it will work? Just use the `$laatsteposts` as I've shown. I'm 100% sure the code above works.

Comment: I have the exact same thing you said to me: http://imgur.com/a/3ZFht
And I does not work and give me the error: `Undefined variable: laatsteposts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\resources\views\home\index.blade.php)`

Even in the PostController the variable is called `$laatsteposts`

Comment: It is. It is: `return view('showposts')->with('laatsteposts', $laatsteposts);`

Comment: There are no miracles. So, check everything. Maybe you're executing a different controller method or something (try to remove `return view()` part at all to see if the view is rendered or not or something).

Comment: I have a strong feeling I need to add something to my routes? Am i right?

Comment: @feudelcosine148 I don't see your routes, so I can't tell. Just double check everything and you'll find the problem.

Comment: @feudelcosine148 you don't have a route for `PostController@index`

Comment: Is it possible you do not have a post in there so its throwing that error because its null? try to dd($laatsteposts) at the top of the view to see what you get. If there is nothing there then account for that. This will also ensure you are getting to the view ( @AlexeyMezenin mentioned you do not have a route for that in the link you sent ).